# Can my laptop run ubuntu? // Problems with the nvidia graphic?

Tags: graphics, laptop, msi

My laptop is a MSI, PX60 2QD-084XES (Prestige) .

Specifications:
* Intel® Core i7-5700HQ (2.7 GHz, 6 MB)
* RAM 16GB DDR3 SODIMM (2x8GB)
* Hard disk 1TB (7200 rpm S-ATA)+ 256GB SSD (1x256GB M.2 SATA)
* Nvidia GeForce GTX 950M 2GB GDDR5

I tried to install ubuntu 14.04 (I have also installed Windows 10), and it seems to be installed correctly. However, when I do updates of the packages, it seems to be going well, but when I reboot the system, I cannot login in, it crashes.

I do not if my computer does not support Ubuntu, or maybe, I suspect that it is a problem with the Nvidia driver...
what do you think? Many thanks!

Comment: ANY laptop can run Ubuntu. And since you can install it so does yours. But you will need to provide specifics about the crashes. /var/log/* will have information.

Comment: NVidia cards are known to cause problems in Linux. Try booting into recovery mode, and work from the command line, using instructions from this site https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia.

Answer (score 2):

First of all uninstall all currently installed NVIDIA software.

Highlight the Ubuntu entry in the GRUB boot menu and press the <kbd>E</kbd> key.
Add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the end of the linux line - press <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot.

On the login screen press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.
Enter user name and password - execute :

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*  
sudo reboot
```

Now install the latest official NVIDIA drivers for GTX 950M.

Highlight the Ubuntu entry in the GRUB boot menu and press the <kbd>E</kbd> key.
Add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the end of the linux line - press <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot.

On the login screen press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.
Enter user name and password - execute :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-358 nvidia-prime
sudo reboot
```

Note :

Generally you should use the NVIDIA drivers from the Ubuntu repositories. But when there are problems with the drivers ... then you can install the latest official NVIDIA drivers from the GPU Drivers PPA. This often leads to properly working graphics, especially on new NVIDIA adapters.

Comment: installing the official drivers does the trick for me! I used `nvidia-378` since it seems to be the latest I `nvidia-358` seems to be gone.

couldn't get it to work with `nouvea-modeset=0` so instead just went into the recovery startup and then with failsafeX managed to get in.